# How to read first n bytes of buffer and convert to string in NodeJS?

Tags: arrays, node.js, string, character-encoding, buffer

I have a string that was sent over a network and arrived on my server as a Buffer. It has been formatted to my own custom protocol (in theory, haven't implemented yet). I wanted to use the first n bytes for a string that will identify the protocol.

I have done:

```
data.toString('utf8');
```

on the whole buffer but that just gives me the whole packet as a string which is not what I want to achieve.

When the message is recieved, how do I convert a subset of the bytes into a string?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't quite what you were asking, so I won't post this as an answer... but in case anyone arrived here (like me) because they googled "nodejs how to read first n bytes of a buffer": A buffer is just a byte array so you can access using simple array notation. `b[0]` is the first byte, represented as an unsigned integer from 0 to 255.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Buffer.toString()` method accepts `start` and `end` parameters, which you can use to slice out just the subset you want for your substring. This may, depending on your implementation, be faster than allocation a new intermediary `Buffer` like you suggested in your answer.

Check out Node's [`Buffer.toString()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) method for more information.

Comment: Oh, I'm so stupid. But I think I'll still use my method because I made a wrapper class for the Buffer class that has methods in it. But thanks, maybe I can make adaptations to that class to use the Buffer.toString method

Answer (score 5):

I know I'm a bit late  to this, but why not just something like:

```js
buffer.subarray(0, bytes).toString();
```

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted a shorter buffer and that was perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Found out how.

You have to copy the amount of bytes you want into another buffer by calling the method copy on the original buffer i.e:

```
sourceBuffer.copy(targetBuffer, targetStartIndex, sourceStartIndex, sourceEndIndex)
```

This will give your targetBuffer the required data which you can then call toString() or any other metod to convert the buffer array into your desired data type.